# Diagonal of the matrix

Tags: python, matrix, integer, diagonal

My task was to find the diagonal of the matrix and then convert the individual values into 0 or 1. 1 when value is >= 0 and 0 when value is < 0. Here is my code:

```
A = [[2, 4, 5], 
    [-5, 0, 9],
    [-6, 7, -1]]
n = 3
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n): 
        if(i == j): 
            if(A[i] < 0):
                A[i] == 0
            elif(A[i]>0 & A[i] == 0):
                A[i] == 1
        else:
            pass
print(A)
```

I constantly get this error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: If you're only touching the diagonal elements, you don't need nested loops...you can remove the inner loop, and use `A[i][i]` to refer to the diagonal elements.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is a square matrix, the inner loop is unnecessary.

```py
A = [[2, 4, 5], 
    [-5, 0, 9],
    [-6, 7, -1]]

n = 3
for i in range(n):
    if A[i][i] < 0:
        A[i][i] = 0
    elif A[i][i] >= 0:
        A[i][i] = 1
    else:
        pass
A
# [[1, 4, 5], 
#  [-5, 1, 9], 
#  [-6, 7, 0]]
```

I improved your code into a working one:

```py
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n): 
        if(i == j): 
            # A[i] is a list, A[i][j] is an element
            if(A[i][j] < 0):
                # == is a comparison operator, = is assignment
                A[i][j] = 0
            # a number cannot be greater than zero and equal to zero at the same time
            # use or not and
            elif(A[i][j]>0 or A[i][j] == 0):
                A[i][j] = 1
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `A[i][j]` instead.

For

```
A = [[2, 4, 5], 
    [-5, 0, 9],
    [-6, 7, -1]]
```

`A[0]` gives `[2, 4, 5]`, while `A[0][0]` gives `2`.